# Reading jpeg headers

Tags: php, objective-c, jpeg

I am new to working with jpeg images in this way but have got so far manage to: get my iPad app to send an image to an SQL database; get a php page to read the stored data and display the image. However I am trying to also read the header which I thought should contain **photoID** (sent using Xcode script shown below)

I am using this code to read the headers but I don't understand what is happening. This checks the image in the database and the image is displayed (so I know I have an image) but it says **No header data found**. Can that be true? I thought that the script used to create the http body sent from Xcode includes header information.

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM tblPhotos";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $select);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$img=base64_encode($row['photoData']);
echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64, $img\"/>";
echo "<br>";

$exif = exif_read_data($img, 0, true);
echo $exif === false ? "No header data found.<br />\n" : "Image contains headers<br />\n";


}
```

Xcode script that sends the image to the database.

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", photoID] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[photoRequest setHTTPBody:body];
```

UPDATE:

I have also tried the following which does say that I DO have headers. However no headers are displayed with the foreach loop and vardump($exif) gives me NULL.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$img = base64_encode($row['photoData']);
echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64, $img\"/>";
echo "<br>";

$temp = tmpfile(); 
fwrite($temp, $row['photoData']); 
$exif = exif_read_data($temp, 0, true); 
echo $exif !== false ? "Image contains headers.<br />\n" : "No header data found.<br />\n";
vardump($exif);

 foreach ($exif as $key => $section)  
 {
   foreach ($section as $name => $val) 
   {
     echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
   }
 }

fclose($temp);

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [`exif_read_data()` function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php)? It's pretty clear you're passing a base64 string where PHP is expecting a filename. Also, I think you mean your Objective-C code; Xcode is an IDE.

Comment: I have read the docs (that is where I got the code from to display the image) and I am trying to understand them but I am new to working with jpegs in this way. My question is initially have I sent any header information at all in the POST from Xcode (specifically photoID) and if so how to pick it up using exif and php. A big ask I know but any pointers ... been at this for hours.

Comment: Save the raw (non-base64) image data to a [temp file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) and pass that path to the `exif_read_data()` function. A base64 string is an encoded string of the contents, but that function needs to read a file.

Comment: See the update. I have tried what you have said (I hope .... is reading the data in this way the 'raw' data?) It says I have headers but does not display anything.

Comment: See my suggested answer. `exif_read_data()` requires a path to a file, e.g. `/path/to/file/tmp.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested, but something like this should work.

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM tblPhotos";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $select);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $img = base64_encode($row['photoData']);
    echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64, $img\"/>";
    echo "<br>";

    $temp = tmpfile(); // This gives you a resource handle
    $meta_data = stream_get_meta_data($temp); // Get the handle's metadata
    $temp_path = $meta_data['uri']; // This gives you a path to the resource handle

    if (!is_file($temp_path)) {
        echo "<p>Error! Temp path not found: '$temp_path' Skipping...<br></p>";
        continue;
    }

    fwrite($temp_path, $row['photoData']); // Note I'm using the raw data, not $img

    // Here, though, I'm passing the $temp variable, which stores a path
    $exif = exif_read_data($temp_path, 0, true); // <<< See $temp_path? It's something like /tmp/ablkjdlfjd.tmp or whatever

    echo $exif === false ? "No header data found.<br />\n" : "Image contains headers<br />\n";

    fclose($temp); // This removes the temp file.
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help you are giving me. It is as I have said in the update .... is says I have headers but displays nothing with the loop. Am I referring to the keys correctly in the loop?

Comment: Dude, you're not doing it right in your code (either attempt). Please read more carefully through the code directly above.

Comment: This is the process: 1. Get the data from table. 2. Save the data to a temp file. 3. Pass the temp filename to `exif_read_data()`. 4. Use said data. Also, use `var_dump($exif)` to see what you get back, this will help with your keys/references.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't clear. I mean the result is the same.  I tried what you have posted and it also says I have headers but doesn't echo anything.

Comment: `var_dump($exif)` and post it in your question.

Comment: It says I have headers but then var_dump($exif) says NULL. Appreciate your efforts - Do you know if the Xcode bit is actually sending anything as a header?

Comment: Save the `$row['photoData']` out to a regular (non-temp) file and check it with this tool: http://regex.info/exif.cgi If you have the raw file from the source (where you're trying to send it from), try that file as well. It's entirely possible it doesn't have any exif data, or the format it saves out as (in the database) is incompatible.

Comment: It's because you're comparing [`false === null`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HvbisV), which will give you `false` (meaning it looks like you have data when you don't, `false !== null`, er, is true). Also, this [github issue](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/336) seems to sum up your issue, so I wonder if it's the same problem. Note the references to needing the binary source. I would save the image data to a file instead of a table and test that first, to eliminate the possibility it's being stripped or encoded when you save it to the table.

Comment: I'm also not an Objective-C developer. `:(` It looks fine to me? You might consider that library though: https://github.com/Intervention/image

Comment: Also, use the code in my answer and `var_dump($exif)` that code. What you're showing in your updated code example in the question is not how you should reference the image data, so you're `var_dump()`ing bad data to begin with. *You have to pass a path to an actual file to `exif_read_data()`.* None of the code in your question does that.

Comment: You might also take a break, give your brain a rest. If you've been hammering this for hours, you're probably mentally spent, which can make this that much harder. `:)`

Comment: Very kind - trying all that you have said .... but yes a break is good idea. Thanks again.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths - I updated the answer code. I, myself, made a mistake reading the docs for `tmpfile()` and didn't realize it was passing a file handle instead of a file path. So I've updated it to get the filepath from the handle.